# CodeIgniter login page load and show login page again on local server but working on live server

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I login admin panel locally it redirects and load login page again, not open dashboard of my admin panel but when I am moving my file to live server admin panel works perfectly.

My Login page Code

```
   <?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  ?>
        <div class="login-box-body" class="text-center" style="margin:0 auto;padding:30px;background:#f0f0f0;border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;">
            <div style="margin:0 auto;" class="text-center">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/images/logo.png'); ?>" style="width:300px;" class="text-center img-responsive;" title="<?php echo $title_lg; ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg"><?php echo lang('auth_sign_session'); ?></p>
            <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $message;?></div>
            <?php echo form_open('auth/login');?>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <?php echo form_input($identity);?>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                   <?php echo form_input($password);?>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="checkbox icheck">
                           <!-- <label>
                               <?php /*?> <?php echo form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE, 'id="remember"'); ?><?php echo lang('auth_remember_me'); ?><?php */?>
                            </label>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <?php /*?><?php echo form_submit('submit', lang('auth_login'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat'));?><?php */?>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" style="background-color: #2f76bb;border-color: #2f76bb;">                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php echo form_close();?>
```

above code is my login page code

My Authentication Code

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));
    $this->lang->load('auth');
}
function index()
{
    if ( ! $this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('/', 'refresh');
    }
}
function login()
{
    if ( ! $this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        /* Load */
        $this->load->config('admin/dp_config');
        $this->load->config('common/dp_config');
        /* Valid form */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        /* Data */
        $this->data['title']               = $this->config->item('title');
        $this->data['title_lg']            = $this->config->item('title_lg');
        $this->data['auth_social_network'] = $this->config->item('auth_social_network');
        $this->data['forgot_password']     = $this->config->item('forgot_password');
        $this->data['new_membership']      = $this->config->item('new_membership');
        if ( $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');
            if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember))
            {
                if ( ! $this->ion_auth->is_admin())
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                    redirect('/', 'refresh');
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Data */
                    $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
                    /* Load Template */
                    redirect('admin', 'refresh');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
            $this->data['identity'] = array(
                'name'        => 'identity',
                'id'          => 'identity',
                'type'        => 'email',
                'value'       => $this->form_validation->set_value('identity'),
                'class'       => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => lang('auth_your_email')
            );
            $this->data['password'] = array(
                'name'        => 'password',
                'id'          => 'password',
                'type'        => 'password',
                'class'       => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => lang('auth_your_password')
            );              
            if($this->session->flashdata('message'))
            {
                $this->data['forgot_password'] = TRUE;
            }
            /* Load Template */
            $this->template->auth_render('auth/login', $this->data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('/', 'refresh');
    }
   }
```

This is my Authentication Code.

Thanks For advance

Comment: This information is not enough to help you out. Provide the errors log which you are getting and code snippets.

Comment: please provide the server information as well .Most of the time if the server is **lynx ** it reject the page if there is a single extra semicolon or if the paths are not well defined. So you can check the error log in the server. So you can find the error easily.

Comment: I am not sure but first of all check your .htaccess file and if changes require then do.
and also if any other issue then describe here then we can help to you :)

Comment: In localhost while i login a admin panel that again redirect to login page but that same files in live server work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the following are updated:

1. The **PHP version** (on the local server)
2. The **Codeigniter** version
3. The **Ion_Auth** library

Hope it helps :)

Comment: PHP Version is 7.3.0
Codeigniter version is 3.0.2
Ion_Auth version is 2.5.2

Comment: Update Codeiginter to the latest 3.x.x version. Simply copy the replace the system folder. An upgrade should resolve the issue.